# Owl carouse different animation effect on each slide

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make my carousel to use different effect on each slide.What i have done so long is :

```
var effect = ['flipInX', 'fadeInLeft', 'fadeInRight']
                for(var i=0; i < 3; i++){
                    $("#owl-main").owlCarousel({
                        dots: true,
                        animateIn: effect[i],
                        items: 1,
                        autoplay: true,
                        loop:true,
                    });
                }
```

Is there any solution or i am trying to do something that is not possible? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animation on multiple slide owl carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337019/animation-on-multiple-slide-owl-carousel)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42898338/4248328

Answer (score 0):

according to the docs https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html animateIn only takes bool or string. no arrays allowed.

you could set a new (random) anmiation after each click.

Comment: Will try! Thank you a lot!